# Why doesn't one transaction delay the other transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I run this script:

```
BEGIN TRAN Tran1
DECLARE @HighBid AS Money
SET @HighBid = (SELECT CurrentHighBid FROM eBaySchema.tItem WHERE ItemID = 1)
SET @HighBid = @HighBid * 1.1
WAITFOR DELAY '0:00:30'
UPDATE eBaySchema.tItem SET HighBidderID=4, CurrentHighBid = @HighBid WHERE ItemID = 1
COMMIT TRAN Tran1
```

That will sleep for 30 seconds so it doesn't finish too quickly...
Then I run immediately run this, which is the same logic and wants to update the same row in the same table...

```
BEGIN TRAN Tran1
DECLARE @HighBid AS Money
SET @HighBid = (SELECT CurrentHighBid FROM eBaySchema.tItem WHERE ItemID = 1)
SET @HighBid = @HighBid * 1.1
UPDATE eBaySchema.tItem SET HighBidderID=5, CurrentHighBid = @HighBid WHERE ItemID = 1
COMMIT TRAN Tran1
```

But the the second script shoots right through and doesn't wait for the first script to let go of the table in the UPDATE statement. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running in the same connection (window if SSMS) or different?

Comment: It could also be single atomic operation `UPDATE eBaySchema.tItem SET HighBidderID=4, CurrentHighBid *= 1.1  WHERE ItemID = 1`

Comment: @DaleK Different

Comment: A transaction isn't the same thing as a lock. A Transaction just ensures **all or nothing** operation. So a delay in one transaction doesn't have any effect on another transaction unless the first transaction takes some form of exclusive lock.

Answer (score 2):

While SERIALIZABLE or REPEATABLE READ will prevent the lost update, it will do it by causing a deadlock, which is pretty inconvenient.  Under SERIALIZABLE both sessions will be able to run

```
SET @HighBid = (SELECT CurrentHighBid FROM eBaySchema.tItem with (UPDLOCK) WHERE ItemID = 1)
```

But will hold the Shared lock, and then neither will be able to get the Exclusive lock necessary to update the row, which will result in a deadlock, which SQL Server will resolve by failing one sessions.

To block one transaction until the other commits either use sp_getapplock as @RossBush suggests, or use the UPDLOCK table hint.

```
BEGIN TRAN Tran1
DECLARE @HighBid AS Money
SET @HighBid = (SELECT CurrentHighBid FROM eBaySchema.tItem with (UPDLOCK) WHERE ItemID = 1)
SET @HighBid = @HighBid * 1.1
UPDATE eBaySchema.tItem SET HighBidderID=5, CurrentHighBid = @HighBid WHERE ItemID = 1
COMMIT TRAN Tran1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to serialize access to an update then you can look into the lock hints posted in a comment above. That is probably the cleanest approach. If you need to define a wait time for your lock then you can create a "single point of truth" procedure that serialized access to a critical section with a configurable timeout. This still uses the internal locking mechanism much like -> `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`

```
CREATE MyCriticalUpdateProcedure()
AS
    DECLARE @LockRequestResult INT = 0
    DECLARE @MyTimeoutMiliseconds INT=5000--Wait only five seconds max then timeouit
    
    BEGIN TRAN
    EXEC @LockRequestResult=SP_GETAPPLOCK 'MyCriticalUpdate','Exclusive','Transaction',@MyTimeoutMiliseconds
    IF(@LockRequestResult>=0)BEGIN
        --Critical Section
        DECLARE @HighBid AS Money
        SET @HighBid = (SELECT CurrentHighBid FROM eBaySchema.tItem WHERE ItemID = 1)
        SET @HighBid = @HighBid * 1.1
        UPDATE eBaySchema.tItem SET HighBidderID=5, CurrentHighBid = @HighBid WHERE ItemID = 1
        --Release the lock
        COMMIT TRAN
    END ELSE
    ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Use the currently configured Sql Server Timeout Settings

```
CREATE MyCriticalUpdateProcedure()
AS
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
    BEGIN TRAN
        --Critical Section
        DECLARE @HighBid AS Money
        SET @HighBid = (SELECT CurrentHighBid FROM eBaySchema.tItem WHERE ItemID = 1)
        SET @HighBid = @HighBid * 1.1
        UPDATE eBaySchema.tItem SET HighBidderID=5, CurrentHighBid = @HighBid WHERE ItemID = 1
    COMMIT TRAN
```